# Не работает discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord

Этот код (почти) полный копипаст с интернета, который хоть как то, но должен работать

```
import "dotenv/config"
import Discord from "discord.js"
const { GatewayIntentBits } = Discord


const PREFIX = process.env.PREFIX
const DISCORD_TOKEN = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN



const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [3148800] })




client.once(Discord.Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as "${c.user.tag}"`);
})





client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.substring(0, 1) === "!") {
            message.channel.send("Hello from AI bot"); //Ответ на сообщение, если оно содержит "!" в качестве первого символа 
    }
});




client.login(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Проблема в том, что `client.on` не работает никогда и не по каким причинам. Нужные разрешения у бота есть (аналогичная поделка на питоне работала)

Что я не так делаю?